# Angular - Use multiple pipes in services and components

Tags: angularjs, typescript, pipe

I have something like this

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let object of objects | pipeOne : filterVarOne | pipeTwo : 
         filterVarTwo">
        {{object}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

And to pass that pipe to my component.ts I did something like this

```
import { PipeOne } from '../pipes/one.pipe';
import { PipeTwo } from '../pipes/two.pipe';
import { ListService } from '../services/list.service';

report: any;

list: any;

filterVarOne;
filterVarTwo;

constructor(
    private _pipeOne: PipeOne,
    provate _pipeTwo: PipeTwo,
    private _listService: ListService
){
    this._listService.getList().subcribe(res => {
        this.list = res;
    })
}

applyFilter(){
    this.report = this._pipeOne.transform(this.list, this.filterVarOne);
}
```

With this I was able to get the PipeOne applied but if I try something like this

```
applyFilter(){
    this.report = this._pipeOne.transform(this.list, this.filterVarOne);
    this.report = this._pipeTwo.transform(this.list, this.filterVarTwo);
}
```

Obviously I do not get the result I expect.

My question is: I can combine two Pipes within the code of my component.html...

```
let object of objects | pipeOne : filterVarOne | pipeTwo : filterVarTwo
```

... to something like this? (of course not so absurd)

```
this.report = this._pipeOne.transform(this.list, this.filterVarOne) | 
this._pipeTwo.transform(this.list, this.filterVarTwo);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you need to pass the output from your first pipe as the input for your second pipe:

```
applyFilter(){
    this.report = this._pipeOne.transform(this.list, this.filterVarOne);
    this.report = this._pipeTwo.transform(this.report, this.filterVarTwo);
}
```

In your original code, `pipeTwo` was applied to the unfiltered data, overwriting the results of `pipeOne` in the `report` variable.